# Postman form-data works, but the raw equivalent doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, postman

I have an API that I'm testing with and if I submit my data through "form-data" with the following values it works:

```
key: response[comment]
value: This is a test
```

But if I do some custom JSON in the "raw" tab with the following structure, it doesn't work:

```
{ "response[comment]": "This is a test" }
```

It's driving me nuts to be honest as the server doesn't give me any details on what's wrong.
I have the feeling it's the encoding of the object that goes wrong, but I'm using Angular and I get the same 400 error, while I'm fairly sure it should just work with a JS object as the data on a .post.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand that JSON and www-form-urlencoded are actually different formats? I doubt there is a way to force server to parse JSON encoded payload from the client side.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using x-www-form-urlencoded though, I'm using form-data in Postman, which is JSON ;-)

That's the reason I'm so confused. There must be a header that's off or something.

Answer (score 16):

Ensure your `Content-Type` header!

If your raw data is JSON: `Content-Type: application/json`

I experienced a similar issue to yours: my request was working using the **form-data**, but not as **raw**... and after debugging the request server side, I realised my request Content-Type was `"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"`.. even if **JSON** was selected in the side dropdown...

Hope it saves time to the next one ;)

Answer (score 9):

Okay I found it.

Apparently the "comment[response]" is actually:

```
{"comment":{"response": "something"}}
```

in JSON.

Learned something :)

Answer (score 2):

Select raw option with JSON(application/json).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the one form-data entry was being turned into a header, and wasn't included in the body at all.  It also worked to set the header explicitly rather than entering form-data.  The Content-Type and JSON formatting from other answers were not involved.  I would not expect arbitrary form-data keys to work this way; the only key being used in this case was "ID".

Answer (score 0):

I too had an API and if I submit my data through "form-data" with the following values it works:

**key: survey_answer[answers_json]**

**value: {"2456-9876-4ff7-9807-4097ed21be57":"testing from postman-today "}**

and I tried to convert it to raw data, so finally I could fix this by

**{"survey_answer":{"answers_json": {"2ed4e729-c1fa-4ff7-9807-4097ed21be57":"test from tessa"}}}**

and If your raw data is JSON: set Content-Type: **application/json**

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the url was `localhost/index.php?userId=1` - and I was using raw mode with `{ "username":"abc" }`

Then, I converted the url to `localhost/index.php?userId=1&username=abc` - it is working for `GET` and for `POST` with the following json: `{ "userId":"1","username":"abc" }` and url `localhost/index.php?userId=1&username=abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone but in my case the method drop down was doing a GET instead of a POST. Change it to POST and you should be good to go.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.