# API : Postman form-data works, but the raw equivalent doesn't

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, postman, content-type

I have an API in which if I am sending POST request thru body type : form-data , i am able to see the output. Here is the successful request
[Form-data success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9O5k.png)

But if I use the same data in raw form, it give me this error

```
 "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90083: The request is missing required parameter: grant_type.\r\nCorrelation ID: 742e7aa2-de23-4589-8b5c-c2fadbbe1537\r\nTimestamp: 2022-01-26 21:21:29Z\r\n"
}
```

[Raw data failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9fWg.png)

Here is what Header looks like when the request is successful
[header successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2quQ.png)
The reason i encountered is, if i unselect the Content-type under header at the success (first) scenario, it also gave me the same error.

I also saw this post [Postman form-data works, but the raw equivalent doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760672/postman-form-data-works-but-the-raw-equivalent-doesnt)

But this does not work for my solution

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cypress to send this POST request. I solved this by adding form "true" in the function. I still am not sure how to fix this in POSTMAN

```
headers: 
   {
     Connection: "keep-alive",
     "Content-Type": "form-data"
   },
form: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and [Form Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) are completely different ways to encode data.

If your server-side program expects to receive data encoded as Form Data (and only as Form Data) then it isn't going to be able to handle you sending it JSON instead.